# Guice Assisted Injection with custom Annotations

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, guice-3, assisted-inject

At the moment I use Assisted Injection with Named Parameters like this:

```
public interface Factory {
public MyObject create(@Assisted("string1") String string1, @Assisted("string2") String string2);
}
```

This works great. But I think it is a bit ugly to use Strings as Identifier for my parameters. What I would want to do is the following:

```
public interface Factory {
public MyObject create(@String1 String string1, @String2 String string2);
}
```

So essentially I want custom Assisted Annotations. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, that style of custom `@Assisted` annotations doesn't exist as a feature; the only way to differentiate assisted-inject parameters of the same type is, as you said, to use named `@Assisted` annotations.

What you propose might be implementable, so you could always file a feature request on the Guice site[1] if you think it'd be worthwhile.

My gut instinct is that there wouldn't be *too* much added value with this approach, though, since they'd be too easily confused with normal binding annotations, while the implication of the `@Assisted` annotation is *much* different. Plus, it does take a fair amount of boilerplate to define an annotation type.

1. http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/